# bug in connectivity, how can I load data again if internet is not available?

Tags: flutter, dart

so, I have function which checks if internet connection is available, but when i turn it off and catch error on Error bloc and then turn on internet, data is not loading automatically, only fater hot restart. So, what am i doing wrong?

```
  _checkConnection(NoInternetEvent event, Emitter<PagState> emit) async {
    print(event.result);
    if (event.result == ConnectivityResult.mobile ||
        event.result == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
      final newData = await apiService.getResult(1, state.count);
      emit(state.copyWith(connection: true, result: newData.results));
    }
  }

  Future<bool> isInternetAvailable() async {
    final connectivityResult = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();
    return connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.none;
  }

  void _onLoadData(LoadListEvent event, Emitter<PagState> emit) async {
    final bool isInternetConnected = await isInternetAvailable();
    List<ResultModel> data = [];
    if (isInternetConnected) {
      const nextPage = 1;
      final newData = await apiService.getResult(nextPage, state.count);
      await service.insertPaginatedList(newData.results);
      data = newData.results ?? [];
      emit(state.copyWith(
          connection: true, result: newData.results, page: nextPage));
    } else {
      final cachedData = await service.getCachedList();
      if (cachedData?.isNotEmpty ?? false) {
        data = cachedData ?? [];
      } else {
        data = [];
      }
      emit(state.copyWith(connection: false));
    }
    bool isCached =
        !isInternetConnected || (data.isNotEmpty && !isInternetConnected);
    emit(state.copyWith(result: data, page: state.page, isCached: isCached));
  }
```

this is my home bloc where i handle error and list:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    BlocProvider.of<HomeBloc>(context).add(LoadListEvent());
    Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
      BlocProvider.of<HomeBloc>(context).add(NoInternetEvent(result));
      if (result == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
        BlocProvider.of<HomeBloc>(context).add(LoadListEvent());
    }});
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: const [
          LanguageSwitcher(),
        ],
      ),
      body: BlocBuilder<ErrorBloc, ErrorState>(
        builder: (context, errorState) {
          if (errorState is ShowErrorState) {
            return ErrorTextWidget(
              message: errorState.message,
            );
          } else {
```

so code run to ErrorWidget and when internet turns on again, i can't load data and error is persist

Answer (score 1):

I have explained this scenario in detail in the following article you can have a look at it. I am posting the solution briefly here and providing a backlink to the original article.

Here you have three concerns:

1. How to handle the connectivity change in the application.
2. If there is no connection then what can be reflected on ui.
3. How to efficiently restart the complete state whenever a connection is back if there was no connection initially or in-between.
4. (Optional) How to effectively(conditionally) reload the state when connection is back.

We can divide this into more sections:

1. Create a service that can listen to connection changes.
2. A reusable view that can be used to reflect no internet state.
3. Conditional reloading of state.

To achieve the following here are blocks of it:

1. `ConnectivityService`: A service class for managing connectivity status.

```dart
class ConnectivityService {
  ConnectivityService(this._connectivity)
      : _onConnectivityChanged = _connectivity.onConnectivityChanged
            .map(_onResult)
            .asBroadcastStream();

  // ignore: unused_field
  final Connectivity _connectivity;

  final Stream<bool> _onConnectivityChanged;

  StreamSubscription<bool>? _subscription;

  /// A stream of boolean values indicating the current connectivity status.
  ///
  /// This stream emits `true` when the device has an active connection and
  /// `false` when there's no active connection.
  Stream<bool> get onConnectivityChanged => _onConnectivityChanged;

  bool _hasConnection = false;

  /// Checks if there is an active connection.
  bool get hasActiveConnection => _hasConnection;

  /// Initializes the [ConnectivityService].
  ///
  /// This method should be called to initialize the service. It checks the
  /// initial connectivity status and sets up a listener for connectivity changes.
  Future<ConnectivityService> init() async {
    final result = await _connectivity.checkConnectivity();
    _subscription = onConnectivityChanged.listen(_onChange);
    _hasConnection = _onResult(result);
    return this;
  }

  void _onChange(bool value) {
    _hasConnection = value;
  }

  static bool _onResult(ConnectivityResult result) {
    bool hasConnection = false;

    /// TODO: Add logic to handle for case [vpn] in android and iOS.
    if (result case ConnectivityResult.mobile || ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
      hasConnection = true;
    }

    return hasConnection;
  }

  void dispose() {
    _subscription?.cancel();
    _subscription = null;
  }
}
```

2. `RestartableStateInterface`: An abstract interface class for managing restartable states.

```dart
/// An abstract interface class for managing restartable states.
///
/// Classes implementing this interface are responsible for managing the state
/// that can be loaded, reloaded, and checked for the need of reloading.
abstract interface class RestartableStateInterface {
  /// Loads the state asynchronously.
  ///
  /// Subclasses should implement this method to perform the necessary
  /// operations for loading the state.
  Future<void> loadState();

  /// Reloads the state by calling [loadState] again.
  ///
  /// This method triggers the reloading of the state by invoking the [loadState]
  /// method. Subclasses should implement the [loadState] method to handle the
  /// reloading process.
  Future<void> reloadState();

  /// Checks if the state needs to be reloaded.
  ///
  /// Subclasses should implement this method to provide a logic that determines
  /// whether the state should be reloaded.
  ///
  /// Returns `true` if the state should be reloaded, otherwise `false`.
  bool shouldReload();
}
```

3. `ConnectionAwareMixin`: A mixin that provides connection-aware functionality to a StatefulWidget.

```dart
/// A mixin that provides connection-aware functionality to a [State] of a
/// [StatefulWidget].
///
/// This mixin extends the capabilities of a stateful widget by adding
/// connection-aware behavior. It manages connectivity changes and allows
/// reloading the state when the connection is restored,
/// based on the [shouldReload] logic.
///
/// The mixin requires the stateful widget it is mixed into to implement the
/// [RestartableStateInterface] interface.
mixin ConnectionAwareMixin<T extends StatefulWidget> on State<T> {
  /// Tracks the current connection status.
  bool hasConnection = false;

  bool get initialConnectionState;

  Stream<bool> get onConnectivityChanged;

  /// Subscription for listening to connection changes.
  StreamSubscription<bool>? _subscription;

  /// Notifies the consumers when there is a change in connectivity state.
  ///
  /// The implementing state should override this method to respond to changes
  /// in connection status.
  void onConnectionStateChange();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    hasConnection = initialConnectionState;
    _subscription = onConnectivityChanged.listen(_onChangeConnection);
  }

  /// Listens for changes in connectivity from [ConnectivityService] and notifies
  /// the current state.
  ///
  /// If [ConnectivityService.onConnectivityChanged] emits the same state as
  /// [ConnectivityService.hasActiveConnection], no state update is triggered.
  /// Otherwise, the state is updated and notifies the client with via
  /// [onConnectionStateChange].
  void _onChangeConnection(bool result) {
    hasConnection = result;
    onConnectionStateChange();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _subscription?.cancel();
    _subscription = null;
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

4. `DefaultConnectionAwareStateMixin` : A mixin that provides the provides default UI and behavior for connection changes.

````dart
/// A mixin that provides the provides default UI and behavior for connection
/// changes.
///
/// This mixin is designed to be used in conjunction with the [ConnectionAwareMixin]
/// and enhances its functionality by providing a default implementation for the
/// [build] method. It handles rendering the user interface based on the connection
/// status. If there is an active connection, it uses the [buildPage] method to render
/// the content; otherwise, it displays a default no-connection state.
mixin DefaultConnectionAwareStateMixin<T extends StatefulWidget>
    on ConnectionAwareMixin<T> implements RestartableStateInterface {
  @override
  Stream<bool> get onConnectivityChanged =>
      connectionService.onConnectivityChanged;

  @override
  bool get initialConnectionState => connectionService.hasActiveConnection;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    reloadState();
  }

  /// Reloads the state of a widget in response to connection status changes.
  ///
  /// This method triggers a reload of the widget's state when called.
  /// It is often used to refresh the UI in response to changes in the
  /// connection status or any other relevant data.
  @override
  Future<void> reloadState() async {
    await loadState();
  }

  /// Loads the state of a widget in response to connection status changes.
  ///
  /// This method is responsible for updating the widget's state. It is
  /// often overridden to fetch data from a data source or perform any other
  /// necessary operations when the connection status changes.
  ///
  /// Example:
  /// ```dart
  /// @override
  /// FutureOr<void> loadState() async {
  ///   final newData = await fetchData(); // Fetch data from a data source
  ///   setState(() {
  ///     data = newData; // Update the state with the new data
  ///   });
  /// }
  /// ```
  @override
  Future<void> loadState() async {
    setState(() {});
  }

  /// Determines whether the widget should be reloaded based on connection changes.
  ///
  /// This method provides a way to control whether the widget's state should be
  /// reloaded when the connection is restored. Returning `true` indicates that
  /// the widget's state should be reloaded; returning `false` means that no
  /// reloading will occur.
  ///
  /// Example:
  /// ```dart
  /// @override
  /// bool shouldReload() {
  ///   return data.isEmpty; // Reload only if data is empty
  /// }
  /// ```
  @override
  bool shouldReload() => true;

  /// Default implementation for handling changes in connection status within
  /// a [ConnectionAwareMixin] mixin.
  ///
  /// This method is automatically called when the connection status changes.
  /// It provides a default behavior for responding to changes in connection state.
  /// If [hasConnection] is `true` and the [shouldReload] method returns `true`,
  /// the [reloadState] method is called to reload the state. If either condition
  /// is not met, a call to [setState] is made to update the UI based on the
  /// current connection status.
  @override
  void onConnectionStateChange() {
    if (hasConnection && shouldReload()) {
      reloadState();
    } else {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  /// Describes the part of the user interface represented by this widget where
  /// there is an active connection.
  ///
  /// The implementing state should provide the content to be displayed when there
  /// is an active connection.
  Widget buildPage(BuildContext context);

  /// Default implementation of [State.build] when the state is mixed with
  /// [ConnectionAwareMixin].
  ///
  /// If there is an active connection available, it will render the user interface
  /// provided by [buildPage]. Otherwise, it will provide a default [NoConnectionState]
  /// as a fallback.
  ///
  /// Additionally wraps the [NoConnectionState] with [WillPopScope] to handle
  /// system navigation pop. If there is absence of connection, in that case
  /// pops current flutter activity.
  @protected
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (hasConnection) {
      return buildPage(context);
    } else {
      return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          SystemNavigator.pop(animated: true);
          return false;
        },
        child: NoConnectionState(
          onRetry: reloadState,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}


class NoConnectionState extends StatelessWidget {
  const NoConnectionState({super.key, required this.onRetry});
  final VoidCallback onRetry;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text('No active connection'),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            OutlinedButton(onPressed: onRetry, child: const Text('Retry'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
````

Putting it all together:
https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:1100/1*qmm0ozOTM9E65DvaChe3nw.gif
You can read the complete article here: https://l.linklyhq.com/l/1tqrJ

Full source code:
Git repo: https://l.linklyhq.com/l/1tqrL